# Hover state not working for foreign object

Tags: css, svg, hover

I have a div inside a foreignObject tag which I want to change the color when hovering over it to the same as the fill color for the hexagon. Hover works fine for the hexagon but when you hover over the div nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
.hex {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    fill: transparent;
}

.hex:hover {
    fill: blue;
}
#div1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
#div1:hover {
  fill: blue;
}

    <svg id="viewBox" viewBox="0 0 3000 1000"  width="3000" height="1000">
      <g>
      <use class="hex" xlink:href="#hexshape"/>
        <foreignObject id="h0" x="0" y="120" width="300">
          <div id="div1">div inside SVG.</div>
        </foreignObject>>

      </g>
      <defs>
        <polygon id="hexshape" width="300" height="260" points="300,130 225,260 75,260 0,130 75,0 225,0"></polygon>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0asLzwjv/28/

Comment: Please add `foreignObject{pointer-events:none;}` to your css

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good except two things:

1. `foreignObject` was not provided with `height`. So, that is the reason behind the div not being rendered in your code.
2. `div` takes `background-colour` not `fill`.

I have updated your code with respect to the changes above.

```css
.hex {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: transparent;
}

.hex:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<svg id="viewBox" viewBox="0 0 3000 1000" width="3000" height="1000">
      <g>
      <use class="hex" xlink:href="#hexshape"/>
        <foreignObject id="h0" x="0" y="120" width="300" height="300">
          <div id="div1">div inside SVG.</div>
        </foreignObject>>

      </g>
      <defs>
        <polygon id="hexshape" width="300" height="260" points="300,130 225,260 75,260 0,130 75,0 225,0"></polygon>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: This does not work as needed. Hovering over the hexagon produces the desired color change, but hovering over just the div changes the background color of the div not the div and the hexagon. Setting pointer events to none as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta works.